# How get a matrix from two columns of pair data in r? The diagonal is zero and keep lower-diagonal part?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame looks like following;

```
ID_r ID_c SCORE
A1   A2   0.2
A1   A3   0.2
A1   A4   0.3
A1   A5   0.2
A1   A6   0.2
A2   A3   0.6
A2   A4   0.2
A2   A5   0.2
A2   A6   0.2
A3   A4   0.2
A3   A5   0.2
A3   A6   0.2
A4   A5   0.2
A4   A6   0.9
A5   A6   0.2

    ID_r<-c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A4','A4','A5')
    ID_c<-c('A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A3','A4','A5','A6','A4','A5','A6','A5','A6','A6')
    SCORE<-c(0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.9,0.2)
```

And I want to use the two columns data to generate a matrix
like the following (only keep the lower diagonal part and diaginal is zero). I want to export this matrix to a csv to be use by other software.

```
    A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
A1 0.0   .   .   .   .   .
A2 0.2 0.0   .   .   .   . 
A3 0.2 0.6 0.0   .   .   .
A4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.0   .   .
A5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.0   .
A6 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.9 0.2 0.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df$ID_r <- as.character(df$ID_r)
df$ID_c <- as.character(df$ID_c)
ID <- unique(c(df$ID_r, df$ID_c))
diagDf <- data.frame(ID_r = ID, ID_c = ID, SCORE = "0.0")
newDf <- rbind(df, diagDf) %>% arrange(ID_r, ID_c)

resultDf <- spread(newDf, ID_r, SCORE, fill = ".")
names(resultDf)[1] <- ""
resultDf

      A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
1 A1 0.0   .   .   .   .   .
2 A2 0.2 0.0   .   .   .   .
3 A3 0.2 0.6 0.0   .   .   .
4 A4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.0   .   .
5 A5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.0   .
6 A6 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.9 0.2 0.0
```